# How to split arguments

Tags: discord

I'm trying to make a basic bio command that will use the information from the command and fill in a nice embed message, but I'm having trouble separating the arguments as each one will have multiple spaces, not too sure on how to split the arguments with a character instead of space? Such as ?bio Name;Position;Class;Bio

I've tried .split('~') to split the arguments up but it's not working.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split('~');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    console.log(message.content);



 });

then below is the actual command code

exports.run = (client, message, args) => {

  const charactername = args[0];
  const characterposition = args[1];
  const characterclass = args[2];
  const characterbio = args[3];
```

As said the expected result is that each bit of information would go into a separate part of an embed message, right now it's splitting arguments per space but some bits of information will have numerous spaces; any attempt to make a character split the arguments just isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. That's an easy fix. Change the definition of args to the following:

If you want it split by a space:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
```

If you want it split by a `~`:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split("~");
```